# Is it possible to write a Java client to access Tensorflow Server?

Tags: java, machine-learning, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I set up a simple Tensorflow server with instructions from here https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/serving_advanced, using my own model. Is there a way to make predict requests directly from Java?

If it's possible, please provide some source code.

Thanks!

Comment: i bet its possible but nobody will do it for you. this community is here to help you with specific problems and not to write all code for you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes can use the tensorflow Java API, [doc here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/java/reference/org/tensorflow/package-summary). And the java api is experimental.

Comment: This answer misses the point, the Java API is for in-process or at least same-machine model execution, not for accessing a tensorflow-serving model server.